# Shell - Reading backslash in command line parameters

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I'm thinking of writing a script for cygwin to cd into a windows directory which is copied from Windows explorer.

e.g.

```
cdw D:\working\test
```

equals to

```
cd /cygdrive/d/working/test
```

But it seems for shell script, all backslashs in parameters are ignored unless using single quote `'D:\working\test'` or double backslashs `D:\\working\\test`.

But in my case it would be very inconvenience because I can't simply paste the directory name in the command line to execute the script.

Is there any way to make `cdw D:\working\test` working?

Comment: \ is an escape character in bash, so I think you're out of luck.

Comment: You could write a shell script taking in the path from stdin. However, you would have to run `cdw` without parameter and then paste the path as an input.

Comment: One warning, in the case that `cdw` is run as a separate script, it will run as a separate process.  While `cdw` may actually `chdir` to the correct location, this will not affect the current directory of the process that called it.  You'd need to define `cdw` as a function for that.

Comment: @HenkLangeveld Thanks for reminding. For me I will do it by `alias cdw=. /home/deqing/scripts/cdw.sh`, so it can still stay in a script.

Comment: Sorry @Deqing, but that won't work.  But another question: How will you get the path to the script, just copy/paste?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can do it, but you want something strange :)

```
cdw()
{
    set $(history | tail -1 )
    shift 2
    path="$*"
    cd $(cygpath "$path")
}
```

Example of usage:

```
$ cdw D:\working\test
$ pwd
/cygdrive/d/working/test
```

The main point here is the usage of `history`. 
You don't use an argument directly, but get it from the history in the form it was typed.

```
$ rawarg() { set $(history | tail -1 ); shift 2; echo "$@"; }
$ rawarg C:\a\b\c\d
C:\a\b\c\d
```

Of course, you can use this trick in a interactive shell only (for obvious reasons).

Comment: it's not safe, if the file name contains a semicolon ';' for example

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul: No, it's safe (or if you are sure that it is not, please provide an example), but of course there are cases when it work incorrect. That's why I've written: "you want something strange"

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul: or better `C:\WINDOWS\; rm -rf /' :)

Comment: I don't get how can `cd $(cygpath "$path")` work. Shouldn't `cd` argument be double-quoted: `cd "$(cygpath "$path")"`?

Comment: @IgorChubin: Hmm... If I set this in my bash init file: 
[pastebin.com/7NuDm89z](http://pastebin.com/7NuDm89z),
I then get: `cdw c:\program files`-> `/cygdrive/c/program files$` 
If I set this in my bash init file: 
[pastebin.com/fzJ1Qrtm](http://pastebin.com/fzJ1Qrtm),  
I then get: `cdw c:\program files`-> `bash: cd: /cygdrive/c/program: No such file or directory`

Comment: @antonio: Ok, than try please: `a=$(cygpath "$path"); cd "$a"`

Comment: @IgorChubin: Clearly that would work. Under what circumstances  will the straight `cd "$(cygpath "$path")"` in [pastebin.com/7NuDm89z](http://pastebin.com/7NuDm89z) not work?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you deal with is related to the shell.  Any argument you add to cdw on the command line, will be processed by the shell *before* `cdw` gets executed.

In order to prevent that processing to happen, you need at least *one* level of quoting,
either by enclosing the whole string in single quotes:

```
cd 'D:\working\test'
```

or with double backslashses:

```
cd D:\\working\test
```

A separate program will not help, because the damage is already done before it runs. ;-)

However, I have a possible `function` for `cdw`, which works in my AST UWIN ksh:

```
function cdw { typeset dir
    read -r dir?"Paste Directory Path: "
    cd ${dir:?}
}
```

And this one works in Bash (which does not support read var?prompt):

```
function cdw {
    typeset dir
    printf "Paste Directory Path: "
    read -r dir || return
    cd ${dir:?}
}
```

For me, I just type the two single quotes around the `Paste`d value.

Comment: You can solve the task without quoting, but, yes, it is a little bit strange; use quotes would be more correct of course

Answer (score 0):

The solution to add single quotes allows to copy paste

Comment: You can do this without quoting; see my solution

Comment: yes, but I don't understand the need, and it's easier to type the single quotes

Comment: It was Deqing who wanted this, I just provided the solution